# react child functional class not re-rendering when I select new link from list

Tags: reactjs

When I try to click on the new link at the new level the Pokemon name will update but not the associate abilities component. Noticed the fetch methods not getting triggered on second link click.

Here is the child class

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { Link, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import "./Abilities.scss"


let Ability = () => {
    useEffect(()=> {fetchAbilities().then(r =>
        console.log("got getting ability"))
    ;},[])
    let props = useLocation();
    // @ts-ignore
    let url = props.state.item.url;
    let [abilities, setAbilities] = useState([]);

    let fetchAbilities= async () => {
        let data = await fetch(url);
        let items = await data.json();
        let abilities1 = items.abilities;
        let denormalized = {
            "name":"",
            "abilities": []
        }
        for(let i = 0; i< abilities1.length; i++){
            let abilityUrl = abilities1[i].ability.url
            let response = await fetch(abilityUrl);
            let promise = await response.json();
            denormalized.name = promise.names;
            // @ts-ignore
            denormalized.abilities.push(promise)
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        setAbilities(denormalized);
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    let getAbilities =(ability)=> {
        let a =<div>
            <div>
                {ability.name}
            </div>
        </div>
        return a;
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    let getAbiltiesFromPokeom = (poke) => {
        let abilities = poke.pokemon.abilities;
        console.log(abilities);
        let li =
            <li className="listItems">
                {(abilities|| []).map((a : any)=>getAbilities(a))}

            </li>
        return li;
    };

    // @ts-ignore
    let abilityName = <>{abilities.name}</>;
    // @ts-ignore
    let effectEntries = <>{abilities.effect_entries}</>;
    let getAbilitInfo =(a: any)=> {
        let div = <div>{a.name}</div>
        //a.abilities[0].effect_changes[0].effect_entries[1]
        let col = [];
        let ab = 0;
        if(a.abilities != undefined ) {
            if(a.abilities.length>0 ) {
                for (let i = 0; i < a.abilities.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        let effectEntry = a.abilities[i].effect_entries[0].effect;
                        let name = a.abilities[1].name
                        let items =
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{name}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>{effectEntry}</div>
                            </div>
                        col.push(items);
                    }
                    catch (e){

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        let div1 = <div>
            <div>
                {col}
            </div>
        </div>;
        return div1
    }
    return <div className="abilities">
        {getAbilitInfo(abilities)}
    </div>
}
export default Ability;
```

Bridge class

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Pokemon.scss"
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, useLocation, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import Ability from "../abilities/Ability";


let Pokemon = () => {
    useEffect(()=> {fetchItems().then(r =>
        console.log("got pokemon details"))
    ;},[])
    let props = useLocation();

    // @ts-ignore
    let url = props.state.item.url;
    let [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);


    let fetchItems = async () => {
        let data = await fetch(url);
        let items = await data.json();
        setPokemon(items);
    }

// @ts-ignore
    let getAbilities =(ability)=> {
        setPokemon(ability)
        let a =
            <Link id={ability.name + "-"}
                  to={{pathname :"/component/abilities/Ability",
                      state: {ability}}}>
            </Link>
        // <Ability ability = {ability}/>
        return a;
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    let getAbiltiesFromPokeom = (poke) => {
        let abilities = poke.pokemon.abilities;
        console.log(abilities);
        let li =
            <li className="listItems">
            {(abilities|| []).map((a : any)=>getAbilities(a))}

        </li>
        return li;
    };
    // @ts-ignore
    let p = <>{props.state.item.name}</>;
    let div = <div >

        <div id="a" >
            <div>
                <p className="poke">{p}</p>
            </div>
            <p className="poke">
                <ul>
                    {getAbiltiesFromPokeom({pokemon})}
                    <Route path="/components/:repo" component={Ability} />
                </ul>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>;
    return div
};
export default Pokemon;
```

patent class

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./LeftHandNav.scss"
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link , useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import Pokemon from "./pokemon/Pokemon";
import Ability from "./abilities/Ability";

function LeftHandNav() {
    useEffect(()=> {fetchItems();},[]);
    // @ts-ignore
    let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
    let [items, setItems] = useState([])

    let fetchItems= async ()=> {
        let data = await fetch(url);
        let items = await data.json();
        setItems(items.results);
    }


    function getLi(item:any, id:number) {
        let li =
            <Link id={item.name + "-" + id}
                  to={{pathname :"/components/pokemon/Pokemon/"+item.name,
                  state: {item}}}
                  >
                <li className="listItems" key={id}>
                    <div className="listItems">
                        {item.name}
                    </div>
                </li>
            </Link>
        return li;
    }
    let id = 0;
    let div =
        <div>
            <div className="hbox">
                <Router>
                    <div id="pokemonNav" >
                        <ul className="listItems">
                            <div>
                                <p>Pokemon</p>
                            </div>
                            {items.map(item =>getLi(item, ++id))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Route path="/components/pokemon/" component={Pokemon} />
                    </div>


                </Router>;
            </div>;
        </div>

    return div
}
export default LeftHandNav;
```

How do I force it to call this again? I added onBlur to asynchonously call the fetch again to update the state, but so far not luck

Comment: add a dependency to your `useEffect`. Assuming, since you are, saving in some variable (state) your current link (pokemon or whatever) and onclick you change the value - then add that variable as a dependency to `useEffect` as so `useEffect(() => // your fetch method //, [variable]`. The dependency makes ti so the `useEffect` fires every time the variable value changes

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now

Comment: Hey, this elaborate a little bit more on the general solution given in the above comment... https://dennyscott.io/use-effect-dependency-array/